# Could not find table 'users' when I use git clone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, clone

I made a project and pushed it to github by the next commands:

```
step 1) create a new repository, is called: todolist
```

and then:

```
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "My first application"
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/alonshmiel/todolist.git
$ git pull origin master
$ git push origin master
```

**I run: git pull origin master, because I read a topic that before the `push`, we need to `pull`**

this is the url of my repository:

```
https://github.com/alonshmiel/todolist.git
```

In my project, I defined `db/seeds.rb`:

```
Role.create({name: "Admin"})
Role.create({name: "Worker"})

user1 = User.create!(
    email: "admin216@gmail.com",
    password: "12345678",
    password_confirmation: "12345678"
)
user1.role_ids = [1]

user2 = User.create!(
    email: "worker216@gmail.com",
    password: "12345678",
    password_confirmation: "12345678"
)
```

when I run the next command:

```
git clone https://github.com/alonshmiel/todolist.git
```

my project is loaded to my computer.

so I run:

`rails s` and enter to `localhost:3000`, but I got an error:

```
Could not find table 'users'
```

can someone tell me what the problem is please? Any help appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

I run:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
$ bundle exec rake db:seed
```

but now, I got an error:

> The website at http://localhost:3000/ seems to be unavailable. The precise error was:
>       Too many redirects

this error didn't appear in my real project, before I uploaded it to github.

this is my `application_controller`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to root_url, :alert => exception.message
  end

  def after_sign_out_path_for(user)
    new_user_session_path
  end

end
```

and these are my other controllers:

```
class TasksadminsController < ApplicationController

  load_and_authorize_resource :except => [:update, :show]

  def index
  ....
end

class WorkersController < ApplicationController

  load_and_authorize_resource :except => [:edit, :update]

  def index
  ....
end
```

Comment: You need to migrate the database because the DB files (`db/*.sqlite3`) will be excluded from version control. `$ bundle exec rake db:migrate`

Comment: @pjumble, I tried it and the error is gone, but why I can't log in with the users that I defined? I got "Invalid email or password."

Comment: how can I put: rake db:migrate in the seeds.rb file? thank you!

Comment: After migrating you also need to run `$ bundle exec rake db:seed` to import/execute the records in the `seeds.rb` file.

Comment: @pjumble, thank you. unfortunately, I got: "The website at http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in seems to be unavailable. The precise error was:

Too many redirects"

I am editing my topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you clone your application you need to bring the database up to the latest version. You can do this by running:

```
rake db:migrate
```

To put the data from `db/seeds.rb` into the database you need to run:

```
rake db:seed
```

The "Too many redirects" error is probably because of the redirect when `CanCan::AccessDenied` is thrown. I suspect that your `root_url` is also needs authentication, which results in another `CanCan::AccessDenied`, which redirects to the `root_url` and on and on.

You should redirect to a page without authentication, like the signup page.

Comment: thank you! I understood it 5 minutes ago and I try to fix it. I want to redirect the user (in the CanCan::AccessDenied) by the next thing: if current_user.role_ids = [1], redirect to "tasksadmins", else if current_user.role_ids = [2], redirect to "workers". I am trying to do something like: if current_user.role_ids == [2]
       redirect_to "workers/index"
   else
       redirect_to "tasksadmins/index"
   end